# grunt build nodejs - multiple projects

Tags: node.js, typescript, build, gruntjs

I'am searching for a good way for building a multi project application.

At the moment I have this structure:
Every app is a nodejs application

```
- parent folder (git root)
|- app1
|-- app1-backend
|-- app1-frontend
|- app2
|- app3
```

at the moment i need to install every app by hand with the following steps:

1. install npm modules with `npm install`
2. install typings with `typings install`
3. compile app with `tsc`

every app folder contains the following: (app1-backend, app1-frontend, app2, app3)

```
tsconfig.json, package.json, typings.json
```

should i automate that with grunt?
Should I use a own grunt file for each project?

greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's already 3 self contained commands, you can probably get by with just adding a script in the package.json of each project that handles all it's building commands, ie:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npm install && typings install && tsc"
  }
}
```

Which will allow you to just run `npm run build` to run all 3 commands for any given project.

Then you can just run
`(cd /path/to/project1 && npm run build) & (cd /path/to/project2 && npm run build) & (cd /path/to/project3 && npm run build)`

Which will build all 3 simultaneously.

*Note: I'm assuming npm will handle multiple processes, but you may have to run sequentially*

It is possible to use grunt to run whatever shell commands such as using [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell); however for me personally, it doesn't make sense to have a build process in one project that will cause another project to build.

Comment: sry i forgot to mention that i use browserify on the app1-frontend project. Can i trigger that too? i run browserify direct after the tsc

Comment: You should, just add another "&& [command]" to the script you add to your package.json for that project.  The core of what you are doing is running a group of commands for each project as a single command, and then running a group of those commands.  As long as the commands are ones that have a definitive end of execution, you can chain as many of them together as you want.  That is to say, as long as one of the command isn't say.. a watch command that waits for a file changes you should be alright